# Ubuntu X server not booting after booting in Intel Integrated Graphics PC

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg

My portable Ubuntu runs on several places, and it seems like it doesn't work on PCs with Nvidia graphics card.

The original PC I installed this Ubuntu into the hard drive is with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070 2-way SLI and with AMD Ryzen 7 1700X (Main PC). Then I unplugged the drive and put it in my workplace, which has Intel i5-4590 and no graphics card(Workplace PC, or Work PC). After work I plugged the drive back into the Main PC it won't boot in X server, but it works on Work PC.

The first time was strange: it still boots in, but in fixed resolution of 640x480. It was due to 'display not found', but it displayed successfully on my monitor with resolution 1920x1080. Then I do dpkg and it works again. After fixing the issue which took me half an hour to figure out solution, the other day I plugged the drive into the Work PC again, did my job smoothly. And then I went back home, plugged it into the Main PC. Tada! No X server booting. I tried to login to tty1 and do startx. Then I noticed that my Xorg.conf was gone, and when i did 'Xorg -configure' it always aborted, and so did startx.

Any solution? I have to use it as portable OS since the Work PC doesn't saves program I installed and I have to reinstall every time I boot, and it's more convenient for me to transfer files along with the OS than putting it into an independent USB Drive.

P.S. sorry for gramatical error, I'm Asian and my English sucks.

P.P.S I'll put system info after I got back home.

Comment: Main PC info:

ASUS Crosshair VI Hero
AMD Ryzen 7 1700X
Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070 2-Way SLI
Corsair Dominator Platinum 64GB @ 2667Mhz (Max 3000)
Two 2TB HDD with Windows 10 installed

Comment: And another thing, I updated Ubuntu in Work PC and it just don't even let me get into tty1 in Main PC afterwards. I can't show the log since I can't access the drive via Windows, and it's not working either in recovery mode.